# Настроить custom breadcrumbs для таксономии

Tags: drupal

помогите пожалуйста настроить модуль custom breadcrumbs для терминов таксономии в drupal7

я пока сделал следующее:

- установил модуль custom breadcrumbs
- настроил отображение крошек для обычных страниц. [скриншот1](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/1.jpg). таким образом при переходе на сраницу пользователь видит путь(в виде ссылок), последним пунктом которого является заголовок страницы(в виде протого текста, то есть не ссылкой). [скриншот](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/0.jpg)
- установил модуль ubercart.  в результате в друпале появилось меню "магазин". [скриншот2](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/2.jpg)
- это меню я поместил в левую колонку сайта. [скриншот3](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/3.jpg)

проблема в том, что у меня не получается настроить хлебные крошки для каталога товаров(меню "магазин") так же как для обычных страниц. то есть чтобы последним пунктом в хлебных крошках было  название раздела или товара в виде простого текста(не ссылки)

например я нахожусь в разделе "мыло". [скриншот4](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/4.jpg). видно, что хлебные крошки содержат только фразу "главная". а мне бы нужно "главная/мыло"

еще пример. я нахожусь на странице товара. [скриншот5](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/5.jpg). видно, что хлебные крошки содержат "Главная » Каталог » мыло » мыло импортное". а мне нужно "Главная » Каталог » мыло » мыло импортное » название мыла"